# Is lightning components' development in scope of Platform Dev 2?

Tags: certification, platform-developer-2

I have started my preparation for Platform Dev 2 (platform Dev 1 already done).While going through the certification guide for this certification, I am trying to understand if Lightning components development is in scope of this exam or not.IF it is, what is the extent to which a developer is expected to know about lightning component development?

While going through the certification guide, in Syllabus under "User interface" topic, it is mentioned:

> Given a set of requirements, describe the process for designing
>   Lightning components.

It is also mentioned in the same guide that developer:

> Can build custom user interfaces to display and interact with
>   Salesforce data using the Lightning component framework, advanced
>   Visualforce, and moderate JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Maybe one or two questions in the exam but not in the programming portion at all. I took the programming part of the exam last fall and LEX never got enabled in my org.

So it won't be required knowledge unless they have made significant changed to the exam, in which case I'm still guessing that it is optional knowledge. Extensive Lightning Experience/Components knowledge isn't required for any of the new Architect-level exams that have come out in the past year and most developers still know very little about it.